# Erro de DLL Relatório Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, visual-basic-6, crystal-reports

Estou tentando gerar um relatório em 'Crystal' no sistema da minha empresa programado em VB6.
Porém, aparace o seguinte erro em anexo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei sobre esta DLL , porém as respostas que obtive não resolveu meu problema.
No aguardo.

Comment: Só um CR deu problema ? Verificou a conexão à base de dados ? Como écesta conexão ? Localizou a dll ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui achar a solução.
Estava faltando duas DLL:'pdssql.dll' e 'ntwdblib.dll' na pasta "Crystal" no nosso servidor.
Copie as DLL de um antigo backup para a pasta atual no servidor e compilei o projeto.